# FFmpeg - how to omit individual frames by the list of their numbers?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an input video and I want to *omit* (or *delete*) individual frames from the next processing (because of the *added disturbing big text* irregularly occurred on top of some individual frames).

I have the `list of ordinal numbers` of these frames but maybe it would be better to `recognize them` during processing by some filter (if it is possible; the text is *the same* and *at the same position*).

Is there some way how to *exclude them from the next processing*?

(The list has about 20 items.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct selection method is simple.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='not(eq(n,45)+eq(n,47)+eq(n,75))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

Frame count starts from zero.  Audio is ignored.

(I'll check for a detection method)

Comment: Thank you very much - you again resolved my problem. I appreciate your wisdom and your goodwill to dedicate a significant part of your precious time to help me and others. - A potential detection method will be of course interesting, too.

Comment: Key to this filtergraph is the "setpts", otherwise it just repeats the last frame it decoded.

Comment: After some study, what you probably want is the "removelogo" filter.
"Suppress a TV station logo, using an image file to determine which pixels comprise the logo. It works by filling in the pixels that comprise the logo with neighboring pixels."